# What's the difference between "react on" and "react to"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, difference

I came across both usages but can't really tell when one is used over the other or discern any subtle difference. Is it a question of American or British English? 
"React on" seems certainly much lesser used than "react to" (see Youtube & Co.). Could someone maybe give some more examples, in case it's just about common phrases like in a figure of speech? Dictionaries only seem to know the latter [[1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/react)] [[2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/react)] [[3](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/react?s=t)]. Somewhat related, [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63788/reaction-to-or-reaction-at) about whether it is also possible to use at. Answers here indicate that one can only use "to" in combination with "react". Does that mean "on" is always wrong?

Comment: I heard "react on" in the sense of "react to" for the first time today as a 54-year old native English speaker. Heard it on a YouTube video made by people in their 20s. And a few hours later I heard it for the second time ever by a different YouTuber from a different country but in the same age group. So I think it's language change in action.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We react **to** a stimulus or situation.

> The dog reacted to the bell by salivating.

The preposition **on** would not head a phrase which refers to that which is being reacted to; it might be adverbial, for example:

> The emergency team can react *on a moment's notice.*
>
> The dog did not react *on the first experiment*.

Or **on** could refer to something which is *affected*:

> These chemicals react on plastics.

From a grammatical perspective, the plastics are not the stimulus. *There is a reaction when the chemicals are applied to plastics.*

We could say:

> These chemicals act on plastics.

But  people often say that the one thing **reacts on** the other.