# Can "reaction on" be used?

Tags: prepositions, difference, collocations

Obviously "reaction to" is correct but I wonder if "reaction on" is correct. If so what is the difference?

Examples:

> People have a positive reaction **to** good things.
> People have a positive reaction **on** good things.

Are these sentences correct? And is there any difference?

I have not found the collocation “reaction on” in any dictionary. However, I found an article where “react on” is used. Also on this site there is the question which might me useful. You can see the following link:

[What's the difference between "react on" and "react to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121545/whats-the-difference-between-react-on-and-react-to)

Comment: Hello mate and welcome to ELL! On this site, we expect people asking questions to have done a little work on their own to find an answer before asking. Did you try searching for "reaction to" and "reaction on"? If you did, please edit your answer (with the small "Edit" button) and include what research you've done. Thanks :)

Comment: Please paste in the quote from the article where you found "react on", and include a link to it. Did you read the answer to that other question? What are you still unsure about?

Comment: The page you have linked to provides a perfectly good answer to your question.